# Python search for modules on sys.path only, ignoring already loaded modules, for existence check purposes

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am looking for a solution to the following problem. I have a package that includes some build tools (for use with SCons, though that is just incidental to the question). I want the package to be able to use these tools itself straight from source before it is installed, so I do the following in the main build file (SConstruct file):

```
sys.path.insert(0, "path_to_my_package")                                                     
import my_package
```

Then great, my tools can be used in the build/install steps of my_package itself (putting it at the front of sys.path to preferentially import it over any other version of `my_package` that might happen to be installed in the environment)

The problem comes in that one of the tools does a "local install" of the package, basically running `conda develop my_package`. Unfortunately, if some version of `my_package` is already installed in the environment, it will be imported preferentially to the local copy "installed" via `conda develop`. So I want to detect whether `my_package` is installed and tell the user to uninstall it before doing the "local install".

However, when talking about "local install"ing `my_package` itself, I run into the problem that in the build scripts I added the package to the path and imported it, so all the normal ways for detecting if a package is installed will think that the package IS installed, because it kind of is within the current Python session. E.g. if I run something like

```
importlib.util.find_spec("my_package")
```

then it will find the copy I am using directly from source, which is not what I care about. I want to check if there is *any other* version of that package already installed in my environment.

I could do something like this:

```
sys.path = sys.path[1:] # remove the local source from the path 
importlib.reload(my_package) # make Python look again for the module
```

and check for import errors, which does work, but I am a little worried about side effects it will have on the version of `my_package` I already loaded the first time. I'd rather do something like with `find_spec` where I can look for packages without actually loading them or messing with the existing `sys.modules`. But I don't know any way to get `find_spec` to properly search the path for `my_package` again. It just always returns the package that is already imported, regardless of what I do to `sys.path`. I guess it looks in some cache or at sys.modules or whatever first.

So, is the some way to search the system for modules totally from scratch, ignoring everything that is currently in the Python session?

I guess I can do something kind of drastic like spawn a fresh Python session as a subprocess via a system call and do the `find_spec` check there. I suppose there is nothing terribly wrong with that, it just feels like there should be a better way to do this...

My other crazy idea was to copy `my_package` to a temporary directory under a different package name, say `my_package_2` and import it from there. It's a simple package so this should be fine. Then when I later search for "properly installed" versions of `my_package` I can do a "normal" search without worrying about collisions. The subprocess thing might be simpler though...

Answer (score 3):

So actually maybe my idea to use symlinks to import the local version under a different name isn't so crazy after all:

```
import os
import sys
import contextlib
from pathlib import Path

@contextlib.contextmanager
def temporary_local_my_package():
    my_package_local_path = "local/path/my_package"
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    linkdir = Path(tmpdir) / "my_package_local"
    try:
        os.symlink(my_package_local_path, linkdir, target_is_directory=True)
        sys.path.insert(0, tmpdir)
        yield
    finally:
        os.unlink(linkdir)
        os.rmdir(tmpdir)

with temporary_my_package_local():
    from my_package_local.tools import stuff_i_need

    ...other build stuff...
```

Then I can do whatever I want inside `my_package.tools`, including searching for the `my_package` module, and it will work in a straightforward way without interference due to `my_package_local`.